# React - Filter Mapped List

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to only show values greater than 0 on each row.

I tried filtering for black > 0 etc but it removed the whole row, whereas i just want to make a 0 into an empty string essentially.

Here is my website / code:

[image: Image of react website]

Any of the 0's in this table i would like to 'hide' or make them an empty string.

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const PRINTER_REST_API_URL = "http://localhost:8080/GetReport";

export type Printer = {
  address: string;
  black: number;
  blackCopies: number;
  blackPrints: number;
  colourCopies: number;
  colourPrints: number;
  cyan: number;
  k1: number;
  k2: number;
  location: string;
  magenta: number;
  name: string;
  serial: string;
  yellow: number;
};

export function GetPrinters() {
  const [printers, setPrinters] = useState<Printer[] | null>();
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(PRINTER_REST_API_URL).then((response) => {
      setPrinters(response.data);
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      {printers
        ? printers.map((printer) => {
            return (
              <tr key={printer.address}>
                <td>{printer.location}</td>
                <td>
                  <a
                    href={"//" + printer.address}
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                  >
                    {printer.address}
                  </a>
                </td>
                <td>{printer.name}</td>
                <td>{printer.serial}</td>
                <td>{printer.black}</td>
                <td>{printer.yellow}</td>
                <td>{printer.magenta}</td>
                <td>{printer.cyan}</td>
                <td>{printer.k1}</td>
                <td>{printer.k2}</td>
                <td>{printer.blackPrints}</td>
                <td>{printer.blackCopies}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })
        : null}
    </>
  );
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Is this perhaps better achieved with CSS or a script?

Comment: You want to add "-" in place of 0 in Black column and rest of the data should be as it is in the black row, right ?

Comment: I wanted to just remove the number if it is less than 1. The question has been solved though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator to make the column empty if the value is 0.

Here is an example :

```
            return (
              <tr key={printer.address}>
                <td>{printer.location}</td>
                <td>
                  <a
                    href={"//" + printer.address}
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                  >
                    {printer.address}
                  </a>
                </td>
                <td>{`${printer.name}` != "0" ? printer.name  : "" }</td>
                <td>{`${printer.serial}` != "0" ? printer.serial  : "" }</td>
                <td>{`${printer.black}` != "0" ? printer.black  : "" }</td>
                <td>{`${printer.yellow}` != "0" ? printer.yellow  : "" }</td>
                <td>{`${printer.magenta}` != "0" ? printer.magenta  : "" }</td>
                <td>{`${printer.cyan}` != "0" ? printer.cyan  : "" }</td>
                <td>{`${printer.k1}` != "0" ? printer.k1  : "" }</td>
                <td>{`${printer.k2}` != "0" ? printer.k2  : "" }</td>
                <td>{`${printer.blackPrints}` != "0" ? printer.blackPrints  : "" }</td>
                <td>{`${printer.blackCopies}` != "0" ? printer.blackCopies  : "" }</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })
```

Comment: Do you need string templating here if you are not doing any replacements?

Answer (score 2):

#### Filtering individual properties to show as empty strings if they are 0

A more concise way to write this would be using `map` which allows you to apply the same function to each of your properties.

```
const properties: (keyof Printer)[] = ["name", "serial", "black", "yellow", "magenta", "cyan", "k1", "k2", "blackPrint", "blackCopies"];
{
properties.map((property) => <td key={property}>{property != "0" ? property : ""}</td>)}
```

### Removing rows where all properties are  0

If you wanted to hide a row, which had all zeroes for its property you could add a filter before mapping to rows:

```
printers
.filter(printer => 
  properties.some((property) => printer[property] != "0"))
.map((printer) => {
  ...
})
```

This is an efficient way of testing if at least one of your properties is nonzero (in this case you would want to show the printer). This is equivalent to testing if all of the entries are zero, but more efficient as [.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#description) exits early the first time a condition is matched.

If you wanted a more semantic way to do this (but slightly less efficient) you could write:

```
printers
.filter(printer => 
  !properties.every(property => printer[property] == "0"))
.map((printer) => {
  ...
})
```

If you wanted both of these features (removing printers which have all 0 properties and filtering 0 properties to be empty strings) the resulting program would look like this:

```
... // The rest of your component
const properties: (keyof Printer)[] = ["name", "serial", "black", "yellow", "magenta", "cyan", "k1", "k2", "blackPrint", "blackCopies"];
return (
    <>
      {printers
        ? printers
         .filter(printer => 
            properties.some(property => printer[property] != "0"))
         .map((printer) => {
            return (
              <tr key={printer.address}>
                <td>{printer.location}</td>
                <td>
                  <a
                    href={"//" + printer.address}
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                  >
                    {printer.address}
                  </a>
                </td>
                {
                  properties.map((property) => <td key={property}>{property != "0" ? property : ""}</td>)
                }
              </tr>
            );
          })
        : null}
    </>
  );
```

Comment: My question already explained I didn't want to remove each row, which is what filter can do. I have used  '{printer.black > 0 ? printer.black : ""}` inside my map function to only show values above 0.